# I want to delete recent app items in Android 7.1

Tags: java, android

I want to delete recent app items in Android 7.1.
I set ***excludeFromRecent ="ture"*** in the manifest.
The problem is the long press of the home key in another application doesn't bring up the first one. Long press the home key while running my app, it's in recent apps item.
How do you solve it?

Comment: Pay attention you are misplelling the value assigned to the option, you are writing ture instead of true